# Hiredis library not loaded/image not found

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, hiredis

I am working on a c++ project using cmake that uses hiredis. The CMake and compilation process do not give any errors. However, when I try to execute my project (from the terminal or from the IDE I'm using [CLion], I get the following error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: libhiredis.0.13.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /Users/connorriley/CLionProjects/DispatchingOptimization/bin/dispatch
>     Reason: image not found

I'm not sure why my project is looking for `libhiredis.0.13.dylib` because the only hiredis library file I have is `libhiredis.dylib.`

My project file structure is the following:

```
. 
+-- bin
|   +-- dispatch (my executable)
+-- lib
|   +-- hiredis
|   |   +-- libhiredis.dylib
|   +-- otherlibs
+-- src
|   +-- source code/subfolders with source code
```

additional info:

- compiler: clang
- os: macOS 10.12.3
- cmake version 3.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set correctly. You can get more information by setting `DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES` and/or some other environment variables mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html)

But probably you just need to add your hiredis directory to `CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` like this:
`set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/hiredis)`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue, it was that I went into my hiredis directory and typed:

```
make
```

but didn't follow that with

```
make install
```

Therefore, the file that my code was looking for was not in my /usr/local/lib